# react when use useeffect for unmount , data not change

Tags: reactjs, components, react-hooks

i use this code in my react project 
when change data1 with usestate , i see data1 is change to 1 but when unmount component data1 is default  value 0 .
whats wrong?
code is:

```
useEffect( () => console.log( ["mount",data1] ), [] );
useEffect( () => console.log( ["will update",data1] ) );
useEffect( () => () => console.log( ["unmount",data1] ), [] );
```

log when mount and change is:

```
["mount", "0"]
["will update", "0"]
["will update", "2"]
["unmount", "0"]
```

Comment: Could you update your code snippet with code related to state variable `data1`? Or, even better, share the whole component.

Comment: These were helpful for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023074/why-is-the-cleanup-function-from-useeffect-called-on-every-render 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020041/react-hooks-useeffect-cleanup-for-only-componentwillunmount

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define your effect like

```
useEffect( () => () => console.log( ["unmount",data1] ), [] );
```

You essentially tell it to run on initial render and hence the data1 that the callback points to is the initial value that it inherited from the closure and is never updated since the function is no longer initialised

If at all, for any reason you want the data1 to be accessible in `useEffect` you must pass it as the second argument to `useEffect`

```
useEffect( () => () => console.log( ["unmount",data1] ), [data1] );
```

In such a case the effect will be cleaned up any change of `data1`

You could also make use of `useRef` to store the data and access it in unmount.

```
function App() {
  const [data1, setData1] = useState(0);
  const refAttr = useRef();
  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      console.log("unmount", refAttr.current);
    },
    []
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setData1(data1 => {
        refAttr.current = data1 + 1;
        return data1 + 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/oo7ojm4k5)

Comment: i need unmount mod.when add data1 at end , useEffect run when data1 change not when unmount. how can get data1 just when unmount with hooks?

Comment: If you add data1 at the end, useEffect will run the callback  on data1 change but will also run it on unmount. The other way is to make use of `useRef` to store data in it and then get data from it in useEffect

Comment: Updated the answer with a solution using ref

Answer (score 2):

i finaly  use this function for get last data when unmount

thanks from "nima arefi" for write it

```
const useTaskBeforeUnmount = ( calback, ...data ) => {
        const mounted = React.useRef( null );

        React.useEffect( () => {
            mounted.current = true;
            return () => {
                mounted.current = false;
            };
        }, [] );

        React.useEffect(
            () => () => {
                if ( !mounted.current ) {
                    calback( { ...data } );
                }
            },
            [ calback, ...data ],
        );
    };
```

then use it in my component like this

```
useTaskBeforeUnmount( console.log, data1, data2, data3 );
```