# componentWillUnmount with React useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-lifecycle

How can the `useEffect` hook (or any other hook for that matter) be used to replicate `componentWillUnmount`?

In a traditional class component I would do something like this:

```
class Effect extends React.PureComponent {
    componentDidMount() { console.log("MOUNT", this.props); }
    componentWillUnmount() { console.log("UNMOUNT", this.props); }
    render() { return null; }
}
```

With the `useEffect` hook:

```
function Effect(props) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("MOUNT", props);

    return () => console.log("UNMOUNT", props)
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

(Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2oo7zqzx1n)

This does not work, since the "cleanup" function returned in `useEffect` captures the props as they were during mount and not state of the props during unmount.

How could I get the latest version of the props in `useEffect` clean up *without* running the function body (or cleanup) on every prop change?

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020041/react-hooks-useeffect-cleanup-for-only-componentwillunmount) does not address the part of having access to the latest props.

The [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) state:

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run.

In this case however I depend on the props... but only for the cleanup part...

Comment: What is it that you want to do when the component is unmounted? There might be some other way of going about it.

Comment: This is more a general question, since I wonder if there are cases which are not possible to replicate with hooks yet. But a concrete example would be storing the props into localStorage, IndexDB, or similar on unmount and reading them back on mount. I do not think this should be done on every prop change (e.g. keypress (if we render input fields)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can make use of useRef and store the props to be used within a closure such as render useEffect return callback method

```
function Home(props) {
  const val = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      val.current = props;
    },
    [props]
  );
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log(props, val.current);
    };
  }, []);
  return <div>Home</div>;
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/5mv0pyknpp)

However a better way is to pass on the second argument to `useEffect` so that the cleanup and initialisation happens on any change of desired props

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    console.log(props.current);
  };
}, [props.current]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Using `useRef` works. I also applied your technique to the initial example (referenced in the question) here: https://codesandbox.io/s/48w5m9pkwx for reference purposes.

Comment: While this is the correct answer... it is still extremely unergonomic, especially when you're also depending on local state. Using a class component is sometimes the better way to go.

Comment: I'd refactor this solution into a custom hook. I'm calling mine `useStateEffect`, and the main difference is that the dependencies are passed to the effect function as arguments, which is how you access the current values.

Comment: Here is a link to the appropriate documentation as well: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup. From the docs: "If your effect returns a function, React will run it when it is time to clean up:"

Answer (score 23):

useLayoutEffect() is your answer in 2021

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        // Your code here.
    }
}, [])
```

This is equivalent to ComponentWillUnmount.

99% of the time you want to use useEffect, but if you want to perform any actions before unmounting the DOM then you can use the code I provided.

Comment: I am sorry, but this does not solve the problem I raised. I need access to the props at point of unmounting and `useLayoutEffect` behaves no different than `useEffect` with the regards of running only on dependency changes (the empty array you passed). Therefor your solution only has access to the initial props of the FunctionComponent and not the "last props" during unmount.

Comment: Ahh sorry! I was up until 6 that morning, so I did not read thoroughly haha.

Comment: I read the top two questions and answered on that. Yeah you have to put the variable you want to keep focus on within useRef for direct access to the newest changes. useEffect() return function actually runs after re-render (making the DOM inaccesible) while useLayoutEffect() return function runs before re-render (making the DOM accesible). This was the cleanest solution I had found and I had thought it was similar to yours. Perhaps this will be of some help anyway in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

`useLayoutEffect` is great for cleaning eventListeners on DOM nodes.

Otherwise, with regular `useEffect` ref.current will be null on time hook triggered

More on react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

```
  import React, { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';

  const audioRef = useRef(null);


  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!audioRef.current) return;

    const progressEvent = (e) => {
      setProgress(audioRef.current.currentTime);
    };

    audioRef.current.addEventListener('timeupdate', progressEvent);

    return () => {
      try {
        audioRef.current.removeEventListener('timeupdate', progressEvent);
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn('could not removeEventListener on timeupdate');
      }
    };
  }, [audioRef.current]);
```

Attach ref to component DOM node

`<audio ref={audioRef} />`

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (elements) {
    const cardNumberElement =
      elements.getElement('cardNumber') ||  // check if we already created an element
      elements.create('cardNumber', defaultInputStyles); // create if we did not
            
    cardNumberElement.mount('#numberInput');
  }
}, [elements]);
```