# Why can't useEffect access my state variable in a return statement?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect

I don't understand why my `useEffect()` React function can't access my Component's state variable. I'm trying to create a log when a user abandons creating a listing in our app and navigates to another page. I'm using the `useEffect()` `return` method of replicating the `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle method. Can you help?

### Code Sample

```
  let[progress, setProgress] = React.useState(0)

  ... user starts building their listing, causing progress to increment ...

  console.log(`progress outside useEffect: ${progress}`)
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => logAbandonListing()
  }, [])
  const logAbandonListing = () => {
    console.log(`progress inside: ${progress}`)
    if (progress > 0) {
      addToLog(userId)
    }
  }
```

### Expected Behavior

The code would reach `addToLog()`, causing this behavior to be logged.

### Observed Behavior

This is what happens when a user types something into their listing, causing `progress` to increment, and then leaves the page.

- The `useEffect()` method works perfectly, and fires the `logAbandonListing()` function
- The first `console.log()` (above `useEffect`) logs something greater than 0 for the `progress` state
- The second `console.log()` logs 0 for the `progress` state, disabling the code to return `true` for the `if` statement and reach the `addToLog()` function.

#### Environment

- Local dev environment of an app built with Next.js running in Firefox 76.0.1
- nextjs v 8.1.0
- react v 16.8.6

I'd really appreciate some help understanding what's going on here. Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think it is a typical stale closure problem. And it is hard to understand at first.

With the empty dependency array the useEffect will be run only once. And it will access the state from that one run. So it will have a reference from the logAbandonListing function from this moment. This function will access the state from this moment also. You can resolve the problem more than one way.

One of them is to add the state variable to your dependency.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => logAbandonListing()
  }, [progress])
```

Another solution is that you set the state value to a ref. And the reference of the ref is not changing, so you will always see the freshest value.

```
let[progress, setProgress] = React.useState(0);
const progressRef = React.createRef();
progressRef.current = progress;

...

  const logAbandonListing = () => {
    console.log(`progress inside: ${progressRef.current}`)
    if (progressRef.current > 0) {
      addToLog(userId)
    }
  }
```

If userId is changing too, then you should add it to the dependency or a reference.

Comment: *-"With the empty dependency array the useEffect will be run only once."*

This made it click in my head, thanks so much!

Comment: I had to use `useRef`. With `createRef` the `.current` seems read-only.

Comment: Great answer, the issue is just a problem of `stale closure problem`.  React hooks heavily depends on `closure`, besides `useEffect` hook, if your new value based on old value defined by `useState` hook, than make sure you pass a function of form: `setNewState((currentValue) => newValue)` to set new state, **React** will assure you always gets the freshest state value when updating.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was using state to store the ref for setInterval, and was getting a similar problem. Never occurred to me to use ref, even when it is blatantly named in the variable.

Answer (score 7):

To do something in the state's current value in the `useEffect`'s return function where the `useEffects` dependencies are am empty array `[]`,  you could use `useReducer`. This way you can avoid the stale closure issue and update the state from the `useReducer`'s `dispatch` function.

Example would be:

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "set":
      return action.payload;
    case "unMount":
      console.log("This note has been closed: " + state); // This note has been closed: 201
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function NoteEditor({ initialNoteId }) {
  const [noteId, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialNoteId);

  useEffect(function logBeforeUnMount() {
    return () => dispatch({ type: "unMount" });
  }, []);


  return <div>{noteId}</div>;
}
export default NoteEditor;
```

More info on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456803/how-to-access-state-when-component-unmount-with-react-hooks)

Answer (score 1):

When you return a function from `useEffect`, it behaves like `componentWillUnmount` so I think it only runs while cleaning up. You'd need to actually call `logAbandonListing` like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  logAbandonListing();
}, []);
```

So it runs everytime a component re-renders. You can read more about `useEffect` on https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

It's written excellently.

Comment: From what I understand, this actually invokes useEffect() in a way that mirrors componentWillMount() in a React class-based component. The return before logAbandonedListing() is key, because that changes the way that the hook behaves to mirror componentWillUnmount(), which is what I'm looking for here.

Comment: it mirrors `componentDidMount()` as well as `componentWillMount()` i think & if u return it behaves like `componentWillUnmount()`. saw u found the answer. typical closure. i also thought about that but finally thought `componentWillUnmount()` was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-galois-6rsgs) to explain my answer.

Basically you are returning a function from your useEffect Callback. But that returned function is never really invoked so it does no actually execute and thus log the abandon action. If you look at the Code in the sandbox I have added a wrapper Parens and () afterwards to actually cause the method to be invoked leading to console.log executing.