# How to setstate after fetch data React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

**Code** : 
[image]

**Result** : Not have data in state
[image]

  help me pls , thanks!

Comment: books default is [] . "const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);"

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(tmp)` in the function?

Comment: Please copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly next time. It helps others to help you. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous that's why you are seeing books as empty array. Here is a quote from the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> The setState function is used to update the state. It accepts a new
>   state value and **enqueues** a re-render of the component.

One thing you may be doing wrong is in your `useEffect` callback. If your effect returns a function, React will run it when it is time to clean up. And you don't want the `setState` functions in `fetchData` to be invoked during clean up as the component will probably be unmounted.

If you just want the `fetchData` to only run once after the component mounts, here is a possible solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // put the fetchData inside the effect
  async function fetchData() {
    setLoading(true);
    const name = await getNameGroup();
    const tmp = await getAll(name);
    console.log(tmp);
    setBooks(tmp);
    console.log(books); // may not be the same as tmp, but you will see the updated state in the next render
    setLoading(false);
  }
  fetchData();
},[]}
```

You should read more about `useEffect` hook in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's a stale closure problem.

Your `useEffect` where the `fetchData` is being called, has an empty dependency array. Within the `fetchData` function, which is inside `useEffect`, you are trying to print `books` which one first load, was initialized with an empty array.

All hooks hold the same reference to the variables with which they were initialized, till the dependencies change. To get an updated state, they depend on the dependency array. Since your dependency array doesn't specify `books`, it won't refresh the reference of `books` in your `fetchData` function either. Read more about the stale closure problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956823/why-cant-useeffect-access-my-state-variable-in-a-return-statement)

That's why your `book`s variable is showing stale data.

```
export default function() {
    // fetch data here
    // runs only once because of empty dependency array
    useEffect(() => { 
      let isCancelled = false

       // define the fetchData inside the `useEffect` so that 
       // you can detect if the component has been unmounted      
       // using `isCancelled`
       const fetchData = async () => {
          const tmp = await getAll()

          // only update state if component isn't unmounted
          // if you try to update state on an unmounted component,
          // React will throw an error
          if (!isCancelled) {
             setIsLoading(false)
             setBooks(tmp)
          }
       }

       if (!isCancelled) {
         setIsLoading(true)
         fetchData()
       } 

       // cleanup
       return () => {
         isCancelled = true
       }
    }, [])

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [dataArray, setDataArray] = useState([]);

async function fetchData() {
    try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const response = await getNameGroup();
        setDataArray(response);
    } catch(error) {
       // handle error
    } finally {
       setIsLoading(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example code that is working and you can apply:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]); 
const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);

async function fetchData() {
const LibraryQuery = JSON.stringify({query: `query { species { id name description } }`});
const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/graphql',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-Token': token
    },
    body: LibraryQuery
});
res
    .json()
    .then(res => setData(res.data))
    .catch(err => setErrors(err));
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```