# useEffect/componentWillUnmount fires but state is empty

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a hook component that allows a user to upload a set of images. I want to set it up in such a way that when the component is un mounted that all the files are uploaded to my backend.

currently using `useEffect` with a return of a function as the componentWillUnmount substitute, however when the function is called the state that it requires (the set of files uploaded) is empty i.e. empty list. Is there a way to fix this or a better way to do it? I suspect its because the useState for the `stagedUploadedImages` is set to an empty list. **Its not an option to lift the state out of this component.**

```js
  const [stagedUploadedImages, setStagedUploadedImages] = useState([]);

  const uploadStagedFiles = () => { 
// when this is reached by the useEffect method `stagedUPloadedImages` is empty list
    stagedUploadedImages.forEach((file) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("files", file);

      api.uploads.uploadWithNoAssociation(formData).then((response) => {
        console.log("ImageGallery: response: ", response);
      });
    });
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      uploadStagedFiles();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleUpload = (files) => {
      setStagedUploadedImages([...files]);
  };
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setStagedUploadedImages()`?

Comment: I call it in the add images logic

Comment: You should use [`useCallback()`](https://dmitripavlutin.com/dont-overuse-react-usecallback/).

Comment: @BenM the button that "submits" the form is not in this component, it is in the parent. And I can not make special code in the parent just for this component.

Comment: @BenM if I wrap `uploadStagedFiles` in `useCallback` it still fails.

Comment: Could you share the code where setStagedUploadedImages() is called in this component?

Comment: @AlexColeman see the bottom of the question

Comment: I believe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956823/why-cant-useeffect-access-my-state-variable-in-a-return-statement

Comment: @SzabóSebestyén It worked if they upload all their files at the same time and therefore only cause the component to rerender once however if they upload the files separately, then it will cause the uploadStagedFiles to fire the second time thereby uploading the first set of files. Which is not what I want.

Comment: @SwimMaster Have you tried the createRef solution in the example? Adding to the dependency list is an obvious no go in your case.

Comment: @SzabóSebestyén I made the value a ref and it was still an empty list in stagedUploadedImages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation: https://www.timveletta.com/blog/2020-07-14-accessing-react-state-in-your-component-cleanup-with-hooks/

```
const [stagedUploadedImages, setStagedUploadedImages] = useState([]);

const valueRef = useRef();

const uploadStagedFiles = () => { 
  valueRef.current.forEach((file) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("files", file);

    api.uploads.uploadWithNoAssociation(formData).then((response) => {
      console.log("ImageGallery: response: ", response);
    });
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  valueRef.current = stagedUploadedImages;
}, [stagedUploadedImages]);

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    uploadStagedFiles();
  };
}, []);
```

Additional info: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/