# Achieve ComponentWillUnmount with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working wtih a requirement where I have to send to the server whatever a user types in a form (even if he doesn't submit it).

Before hooks I would use **componentWillUnmount** and grab all the state variables and send it to the backend, easy peasy.

Now with hooks things changed and this is where my struggles start. I know that I can achieve the **ComponentWillUnmount** with this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        //the code for unmount
    }
}, []);
```

However this is not as simple as I need to have a variable in the useeffect "[]" or i will run into stale closure problem as describbed here [Why can't useEffect access my state variable in a return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956823/why-cant-useeffect-access-my-state-variable-in-a-return-statement) . What this means is that if I leave it as "[]" my state variables will be null.

My question is how would it be a clean solution? I don't have a variable that I know that it will necessarily change in the particular form, so I don't have a good variable to put on the "[]".

I thought that maybe I would create a "dirty" variable that if at least one field changed it would set it to true and I could use this variable for the [] in the useEffect, but this seems like a bit of work for something that should be much simpler.

Does anyone has a clue of an elegant solution for this?

Comment: Can you tell what exactly you want to cleanup? Add a minimal reproducible example in the question.

Comment: For this use case I don't want to necessarily clean up anything. I want to grab a bunch of variables in the state and send to the backend the information the user filled in the form

Comment: Why not send them at every change (with debounce)? Why wait for the component to unmount?

Comment: I thought about that, but in this particular case it wouldn't be good as it would generate a lot of requests and very quickly the server would be in trouble to deal with such a big amount of requests

Comment: If you still want to do it only on unmount, then maybe you can store your data in `useRef` instead of `useState` and then use the ref to get the latest data in unmount code. [Do note that using refs doesn't re-render the component on changes to the object. You will have to manually trigger re-render. or, you could probably keep using `useState` and whenever something in your state changes, update it in the ref]

Comment: I think you are trying to do something like auto save. Your server should, ideally, scale to handle the big volume of requests. If not, you could probably increase the `debounce` time to reduce the number of requests. Most of the time, your server is going to be idle, so, why not just make it work 

Comment: thanks for poiting for the debounce solution, will use it for it. seems the best one for this