# React component state resets at unmounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I need to persist step form's data as if the user clicks on other step. So during unmounting of step form component, I need to update the state to REDUX store

#### Issue

The state seems to be resetting to default as soon as I am accessing it while unmounting;

```js
// local state 
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    named: [{ id: uuid(), value: '', name: '', type: ' ' }], //  initial state
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // update redux state before unmounting
    return () => {
      //  sets itself to initial state ignoring what user has typed
      console.log(state); // prints [{ id: uuid(), value: '', name: '', type: ' ' }]       
      updateStepThreeReduxState(state); // redux action
    };
  }, []);
```

Is there any way we can get an access to the state just before unmouting ??

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456803/how-to-access-state-when-component-unmount-with-react-hooks

Answer (score 1):

State and updateStepThreeReduxState are dependencies of your effect:

```
//custom hook defined outside the component
function useIsMounted() {
  const isMounted = useRef(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false
    }
  }, [])
  return () => isMounted.current
}

// local state
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
  named: [{ id: uuid(), value: '', name: '', type: ' ' }], //  initial state
});
const mounted = useIsMounted()
React.useEffect(() => {
  // update redux state before unmounting
  return () => {
    if(!mounted()){
      console.log(state); // prints [{ id: uuid(), value: '', name: '', type: ' ' }]
      updateStepThreeReduxState(state); // redux action
    }
  };
}, [state, updateStepThreeReduxState,mounted]);//<- added dependencies
```

Because you didn't add it to dependencies you have a state value that is a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). Missing dependencies should cause a warning with the [linter](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920), create react app should have set all of this up for you so either use create-react-app or stop ignoring the warnings it produces.

Comment: This resulted in infinite renders

Comment: @KaranKumar I updated the answer, the effect will only run if the component is unmounted.