# How to Unmount React Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I've built several modals as React functional components.  They were shown/hidden via an `isModalOpen` boolean property in the modal's associated Context.  This has worked great.

Now, for various reasons, a colleague needs me to refactor this code and instead control the visibility of the modal at one level higher.  Here's some sample code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { UsersProvider } from '../../../contexts/UsersContext';
import AddUsers from './AddUsers';

const AddUsersLauncher = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <UsersProvider>
        <Button onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>Add Users</Button>
        {showModal && <AddUsers />}
      </UsersProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddUsersLauncher;
```

This all works great initially.  A button is rendered and when that button is pressed then the modal is shown.

The problem lies with how to hide it.  Before I was just setting `isModalOpen` to false in the reducer.

When I had a quick conversation with my colleague earlier today, he said that the code above would work and I wouldn't have to pass anything into `AddUsers`.  I'm thinking though that I need to pass the `setShowModal` function into the component as it could then be called to hide the modal.

But I'm open to the possibility that I'm not seeing a much simpler way to do this.  Might there be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leave `showModal` as state variable in `AddUsersLauncher` and change it from within  `AddUsers`, then yes, you have to pass the reference of `setShowModal` to `AddUsers`. State management in React can become messy in two-way data flows, so I would advise you to have a look at [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) for storing and changing state shared by multiple components

Comment: Thanks for this.  Your thinking about the need to pass `setShowModal` into `AddUsers` echoes my thinking but my colleague was insistent that this wasn't necessary.  I'll ask him about it when he arrives this morning.

As for `Redux` we've decided to not use it for this project and instead use `React Context`.  So far we've found no problems with this alternate state management approach.

Comment: P.S. I was talking with my colleague again about this.  He just hadn't thought through that we needed to eventually close the modal.

Answer (score 17):

To call something on unmount you can use `useEffect`. Whatever you return in the useEffect, that will be called on unmount. For example, in your case

```
const AddUsersLauncher = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // Your code you want to run on unmount.
    };
  }, []); 


  return (
    <div>
      <UsersProvider>
        <Button onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>Add Users</Button>
        {showModal && <AddUsers />}
      </UsersProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Second argument of the useEffect accepts an array, which diff the value of elements to check whether to call useEffect again. Here, I passed empty array `[]`, so, it will call useEffect only once.

If you have passed something else, lets say, `showModal` in the array, then whenever `showModal` value will change, useEffect will call, and will call the returned function if specified.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I was aware of the return in a useEffect as the cleanup function.  But my colleague was insistent that nothing needed to be passed into `<AddUsers />` in order to close it from within this child component.  I couldn't see a way to do this, which is why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

With react 18 components will be mounted twice to test the stability in dev mode.

The logic we write on mount and unMount should respect this paradigm.

**useMount**

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function useMount(run: () => void) {
  const referencedRun = useRef(run);
  useEffect(() => {
    referencedRun.current();
  }, []);
}

export default useMount;
```

**useUnMount**

```
import React, {
  DependencyList,
  EffectCallback,
  useEffect,
  useRef
} from "react";
import useMount from "./useMount";

const useUnMount = (effect: EffectCallback, dependencies?: DependencyList) => {
  const unMounted = useRef(false);

  // with react 18 component will be mounted twice in dev mode, so setting the reference to false on the second mount
  useMount(() => {
    unMounted.current = false;
  });

  // to identify unmount
  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      unMounted.current = true;
    },
    []
  );

  // wrap dependencies with the callback
  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      if (unMounted.current) {
        effect();
      }
    },
    [dependencies, effect]
  );
};

export default useUnMount;
```

**Usage**

```
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");

  useMount(() => {
    console.log("on mount...", val);
  });

  useUnMount(() => {
    console.log("on unmount...", val);
  }, [val]);
```

Notice that on unmount we are passing the dependencies to resolve the latest value.

refer: [react-hooks-useeffect-cleanup-for-only-componentwillunmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020041/react-hooks-useeffect-cleanup-for-only-componentwillunmount/77023641#77023641)