# react hook useEffect cleanup with dynamic prop problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In our application we are attempting to leverage `useEffect` to make an api call on cleanup of a component, something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    myAPIFunction(dynamicProp)
    // api call here that leverages a prop
  }
})
```

The idea here is that we want to make this api call on the tear down of this component. The problem is that as our application progresses `dynamicProp` changes at the component level, but whenever the api call is made we get the value `dynamicProp` as whatever it was initialized at.

If we update it it to the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    myAPIFunction(dynamicProp)
    // api call here that leverages a prop
  }
}, [dynamicProp])
```

It does update the prop in the cleanup function but we really only want to call this once on the component cleanup, and this causes the cleanup to fire any time `dynamicProp` changes.

Is there a solution where we can have `dynamicProp` be .... dynamic in our cleanup without having to run the cleanup every time `dynamicProp` changes?

Comment: Are you saying that in the second case, `myAPIFunction` gets called every time `dynamicProp` changes?

Comment: @tromgy correct

Comment: does this describe what you're seeing? https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

Comment: What indicates in your code that you're performing cleanup? Check for that condition in your useEffect statement.

Comment: You can use useRef for dynamicProp and pass .current to api function.

Comment: You can find detailed discussion of this problem in this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020041/react-hooks-useeffect-cleanup-for-only-componentwillunmount). Check the answer that is using `useRef`. That will work for a case like yours, just like @bigless said. If you want to see a live example, here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/effect-cleanup-unmount-current-state-0cb80?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: great, thanks everyone, i'll give it a go, feel free to drop an answer so i can give cred.

Comment: Another [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/effect-cleanup-unmount-current-state-forked-4z7bv?file=/src/App.js) (probably closer to what @bigless had in mind).

Comment: This has been answered in that thread, so IMHO no credit is due here 