# React Router Dom v6 Detect user is leaving a page and do something

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

When a user is leaving a page or goes to another route, I want a dispatch to happen. Here's some pseudocode:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(userLeave){
     dispatch(clearData())
  }
},[userLeave])
```

Is there a good example of how to create such a dispatch when a user leaves the page or goes to another route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in Component where your route renders:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   return ()=> dispatch(clearData())
},[])
```

for example, you have a '/home' pathname and you are rendering Home Component:

```
const  Home = ()=> {

useEffect(()=>{
    return ()=> dispatch(clearData())
},[])

return (
    <div>
        Hello
    </div>
);
```

}

export default Home;

return in useEffect acts like componentDidUnmount you can use it for your purpose

Comment: This runs even on mount, any idea why?

Comment: not actually, when you return func in useEffect it will be runned after component unmounted.

take a look at here : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1 @GeniusHawlah

Answer (score 0):

try this, i think this might work.

```
       window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = '';
            dispatch(clearData())
        })
```