# In react-native, what would cause the root component to be unmounted?

Tags: android, react-native

Given the following simplified app in react native:

```
    import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
    
    const App = () => {
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log('App mounted');
    
        return () => {
          console.log('App unmounted');
        };
      }, []);
    
      <View>
        <Text>Hello world</Text>
      </View>;
    };
    
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Under what circumstances would `App` be unmounted, and the return function from the `useEffect` be called?

My assumption was "never" (it's either backgrounded, crashed or killed), but that doesn't seem to be the case.  We have a very small minority of users where app is sometimes closing, shortly after being background, and the disposer on the `useEffect` is being called.   And it only seems to be happening on Android.

Any clues?

Comment: common misconception is that the cleanup function only runs when the component unmounts. In fact, they run on every re-render of the component.  See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023074/why-is-the-cleanup-function-from-useeffect-called-on-every-render). Your crash will be hard to diagnose without a repro or stack trace - what's really happening in your cleanup?

Comment: I don't believe that's correct -- according to [this](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update), the cleanup function only runs on unmount due to the dependencies argument being an empty array ([]).   To answer your other question -- there's no error or crash, just a shutdown.